# Hosting JS file without showing code

Tags: javascript

I've got a js script that I would like to host, and allow people to link to the script directly to use on their website. However I would like the user to not be able to see or alter the code.

If I host my script on google will they be able to see the code if they go to the URL in their browser?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You cannot hide JS, the best you can do is obfuscate/uglify it.

Comment: Of course. You can obfuscate/minify/compress your scripts but JavaScript is an interpreted language so _somehow_ they'll always be able too read them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There really isn't anything you can do to prevent the code from being seen. This is because the transmission of Javascript over HTTP is clear text and the browser relies on that so you can't send an encrypted javascript file.

What you CAN do, is to minify and obfuscate the file, so that it is harder to read. This will replace:

```
function compareNumbers(firstNumber, secondNumber) { return firstNumber < secondNumber; }
```

with:

```
function a(b, c) { return b < c; }
```

So it's still somewhat readable, but not as easy to understand.